# Для каждого th в tr поменять цвет

Tags: javascript

Есть у меня вложенный цикл, а в нем строка:

```
<tr id="@i@j">
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
</tr>
```

Как в `javascript` для каждого столбца `th` в `tr` по `id` изменить фон?

Answer (score 1):

```
var mytr = document.getElementById(th.id);
$(mytr).find('th').each(function () {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#dff0d8";
});
```

Comment: jQuery для этого подключать? можно на нативном спокойно все сделать

Answer (score 0):

Сразу ищем `tr` а в нем уже все `th` и для каждого меняем фон

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("#@i@j > th");
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = '#C65858';
}
```